# Merge conflict after pull request

Tags: git, github

My local repo says that everything is up-to-date. However, after creating a pull request on rsschool-cv-html to gh-pages, GitHub tells me there is a merge conflict associated with the readme file (so frustrating).

It would be great if someone could find a way out of this since I have been looking for solutions for quite some time.

Please see my PR: https://github.com/didathehacker/rsschool-cv/pull/2.

Github doesn't allow the merge:
[image: Github doesn't allow the merge]

Terminal says everything is clean:
[image: terminal view]

Sorry not to fully follow the guidelines here, however, this is the last place I'm looking for help.

Comment: Don't worry, the situation is pretty normal. There's already content in the readme. GitHub cannot decide whether https://didathehacker.github.io/rsschool-cv/ or https://didathehacker.github.io/rsschool-cv/cv is the right content. Someone needs to resolve the conflict and all is good. About merge conflicts: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/about-merge-conflicts How to resolve merge conflicts: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github

Comment: Maybe your local copy of `rsschool-cv-html` is out of date with it's upstream branch?